# How to fix unexpected $end error?

Tags: php, mysql

hello iam learning create portal news using php, i was followed step by step on book tutorial.But its always give me a return error :(

iam check again and again my syntax line by line and my code are equal with the tutorial in the books. i think i can not found this error. would be grateful if someone could help me..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<?php

include 'koneksi.php';

$table1=berita;
$table2=kategori;
$id=1;
$hal = $_GET[hal];

if(!isset($_GET['hal'])){
$page = 1;
}else {
$page = $_GET['hal'];
}

$max_result = 2;
echo $page;

$from = (($page * $max_result) - $max_result);
$sql=mysql_query("select * from $table1, $table2 where $table1.id_kategori and $table1.id_kategori=$table2.id_kategori order by tanggal desc limit $from, $max_result;");

while($tampil=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$data=substr($tampil['isi'],0,200);
?>

<div class="box">
<p align="justify">
<img src="<?=$tampil[gambar];?>" align="left">
<font valign="top">
<strong><?php echo $tampil[judul]; ?></strong>"
<?php echo $data;?>
<a href="index.php?menu=detail_politik&id=<?=$tampil['id_berita'];?>">Baca Selengkapnya-->>>></a>
</font></p></div><br>

<?php
}
$total_results = mysql_result(mysql_query("select count(*) as Num from $table1 where $table1.id_kategori=$id"),0);
$total_pages = ceil($total_results/$max_result);
echo "<center>Pilih Halaman<br/>";

if($hal > 1){
$prev = ($page - 1);
echo "<a href=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?menu=politik&hal=$prev><-sebelumnya</a>";
}

for($i = 1; $i <=$total_pages; $i++){
if(($hal) == $i){
echo "$i";
}else{
echo "<a href=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?menu=politik&hal=$i>$i</a>";
}
if($hal < $total_pages){
$next = ($page + 1);
echo "<a href=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?menu=politik&hal=$next>selanjutnya-></a>";
}
echo "</center>"
?>
```

**This code always give me ERROR :**
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\AppServ\www\beritaonline\filepolitik.php on line 48

**and line on 48 is :**
the last line of code, `?>`

whats wrong dear :'((

Comment: get a newer book, this is clearly very dated

Comment: And you can only fix this with proper indentation.

Comment: You use an IDE that shows matching braces, and find the opening brace that doesn't have a matching closing brace

Comment: yet, iam using notepad++ . thanks for coming here and give a suggesstion :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a semicolon `;` after your last `echo`:

```
echo "</center>";
?>
```

In most cases, you won't need the closing php tags `?>` either.

Also, your `for` loop has no closing `}`:

```
for($i = 1; $i <=$total_pages; $i++){
```

This will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

your last for-next cycle is not closed with a }

btw a ; is missing from the last line, too

Comment: thanks for correcting dear..
i cant concentration >.<

Comment: these errors are usually due to something un-closed in the code :)